# OAuth2: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I am trying to get an accesstoken OAuth2 but I am getting this error:

```
'{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'. Trace ID: dd0ee743-c11e-48cc-b67f-91bd771a0500 Correlation ID: c7505426-844c-4dab-a2d9-9744a1af1b1a Timestamp: 2023-12-11 23:00:02Z","error_codes":[900144],"timestamp":"2023-12-11 23:00:02Z","trace_id":"dd0ee743-c11e-48cc-b67f-91bd771a0500","correlation_id":"c7505426-844c-4dab-a2d9-9744a1af1b1a","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=900144"}'
```

Here is my code:

```
    HttpHeadersContent.TryAddWithoutValidation('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    HttpHeadersContent.Add('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', SubKeyTest);
    HttpHeadersContent.TryAddWithoutValidation('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    HttpHeadersContent.Add('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders().Add('grant_type', 'client_credentials');
    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders().Add('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', SubKeyTest);
    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders().Add('client_secret', ClientSecret);
    HttpContent.GetHeaders(HttpHeadersContent);
```

Is there something I am not doing right?

Comment: Yes you are missing the `grant_type` key/value as clearly stated in the error. It's not supposed to be in the header, it needs to be in the body of the content. Same goes for the otehr key/value pairs, they should be in the body eg `var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "grant_type", "client_credentials" }` etc

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions that it expects the grant type in body instead of header. Probably as `FormUrlEncodedContent`.
you can do something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
 {
 { "grant_type", "its value" }
};

var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "url");
request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict);

// Rest of your code to send HttpRequest
```

You can add more items to `dict` if needed.